# Is it possible to strip more than X digits in a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to strip digits from a string, when 6 or more digits are found in the string.

**I don't want to remove *all* the digits in the string, only the 6th and any beyond that. The first 5 need to be kept.**

For example:

```
var val = 'Hello, this is my text. I was born in 1984, and currently my age is 29 years';
if (val.match(/[0-9]/g, '').length > 5) {
    // strip any digits beyond the 5th
}
```

After whatever comes in the if, val should now contain:

```
var val = 'Hello, this is my text. I was born in 1984, and currently my age is 2 years';
```

I feel that there's probably something very easy for this that I'm overlooking. However my searches on the web seemed to yield nothing.

Comment: I believe you are going to need more than a regular expression to do this...

Comment: You may be right, I was hoping maybe it was just something I can't come up with for some reason, but it doesn't look to be the case...

Comment: Why do you need this functionality?

Comment: To strip out phonenumbers, but allow for example a birth year (and no, the check was not my idea ;) ).

Comment: I'm guessing this would be some kind of profile info field, then? Maybe some regexes to check if it contains a phone number, then returning a error message would be an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var val = 'Hello, this is my text. I was born in 1984, and currently my age is 29 years';
var count = 0;
var str = val.replace(/\d/g, function(match){ return (++count<6) ? match : ""; });
console.log(str);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I wasn't aware I could pass a lambda to .replace(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @strikernl—that's not a "closure", it's a function expression.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, I was under the impression a closure / lambda expression was the same thing, oops ;)

Answer (score 0):

epascarello beat me to it with an excellent answer, here's a loop solution anyway.

```
function removeDigits(s, n) {
  var c,
      count = 0,
      t = [];

  // if there are less than n digits, return s
  if (s.replace(/\D/g,'').length < n) {
    return s;
  }

  // Copy the string up to the first n digits
  for (var i=0, iLen=s.length; i<iLen && count < n; i++) {
    c = s.charAt(i);

    if (re.test(c)) ++count;

    t.push(c);
  }

  // Return string so far and remove digits from the rest
  return t.join('') + s.substr(i).replace(/\d/g,'');
}
```